# Can Haskell ignore Ints vs. Integers?

Tags: haskell

I have a program that uses both `Int` and `Integer`, because a few of the functions return results that are quite large. I'm tired of having to use `fromIntegral` everywhere and I was wondering if there's a way to get Haskell to ignore the distinction between `Int` and `Integer` upon compilation.

Comment: No there is not. Ignoring the fact that they are different types and different properties would be evil in a language as well typed as Haskell. I agree it is painful sometimes but ignoring the difference would be worse; and missing the whole point of the type safety that Haskell provides.

Comment: No, there isn't. And it's a good thing: type safety. You can define a conversion with a shorter to type name, though :)

Comment: In GHC at least, `Integer` will internally use `Int` for as long as it can, so it doesn't necessarily make sense to use `Int` in this case.

Comment: @DanielFischer Perfect suggestion. Also, I was thinking that there might be some sort of way to combine `Int` and `Integer` into a supertype with the use of a macro; I wasn't hoping to ignore the type-system altogether!

Comment: @geekosaur Sure, but so many Prelude functions take `Int`s as arguments that I'd still be using `fromIntegral` everywhere.

Comment: There are `generic` versions of some of them in `Data.List`; otherwise use a shorter name for it (many projects have `fi = fromIntegral` somewhere in a utility module).

Comment: I tend to use `Num a => ...` or `Integral a => ...` as much as possible, for a couple of reasons: (1) it avoids using `fromIntegral` all over the place, so it's sort-of equivalent to ignoring the distinction between `Int` and `Integer`, and (2) the code is much more readily extensible. It's never given me any performance problems, but if it did then it wouldn't be much work to experiment with using a concrete type instead of a typeclass and see if that gave me a speedup.

Comment: I'm...surprised by this.  Most `Prelude` functions that take `Int`s as arguments expect those arguments to be relatively small.  `Integer` should only be used for things that can get large.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution: remove the `Int`s from your program and just use all `Integer`s. As noted by geekosaur, you can use [the generic functions from Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#g:26) (e.g. `genericLength`). If you provide us with your specific program code, then we could give more specific suggestions.